# Connecting Ceiling Fan

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Power source in fixture. Two 3-way switches. How do I get constant hot to ceiling fan and work the light with both switches.

Comment: We're going to need a fe pictures of the switch boxes and the ceiling box.

Comment: Can you post photos of the interiors of all boxes involved please? Are you limited to the cables that are there, or are you running new cabling?

Comment: I'm voting to close because OP is so vague that we can't possibly answer, and isn't adding the detail that is needed to help.  Also since the constant hot is already at the fixture, I suspect OP self-solved this with other resources on the Web. If not, OP please [edit] and it'll be reopened.

Comment: I understand exactly what he is asking. What we don't know is what he has available. Existing switches?... # conductors present?... Is this a new install?... 3-way already affecting both?... etc... Personally, I put mine on two sets of 3-ways; one for each circuit.

Comment: I got it figured out... thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

If both switches are not working correctly someone messed up the wiring! We will need a schematic to figure it out.

A schematic is a explanation of the wiring in each of the switch boxes and at the light fixture.

Many times it is a simple screwup when a new switch was installed the person swapped the common with a traveler .

We need pics or a full description, but can help, @harper has some good 3 way posts if you don’t want to provide photos reading up on one of these will give you a path forward.

Comment: I have a feeling that's what OP did... self-solved.